# Dynamic HTML Tables - specific layout query from object data

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to create a set of dynamic HTML tables using JS.

I am taking in data from an array of objects, in the following format:

```
const formPages = [
  {
    "name": "page1",
    "response": [
      {
        "question": "Question 1",
        "response": "Hello!"
      },
      {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "response": "Hello again!"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "page2",
    "response": [
      {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "response": "Bye!"
      },
      {
        "question": "Question 4",
        "response": "Bye again!"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to output a table for each page in the following format:

**Page 1**

| Question | Response |
| --- | --- |
| Question 1 | Hello! |
| Question 2 | Hello Again! |

**Page 2**

| Question | Response |
| --- | --- |
| Question 3 | Bye! |
| Question 4 | Bye Again! |

I know we need to loop over the array of objects, dynamically rendering the HTML to output those two tables.

Don't have much experience with table HTML, so some help here would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like below, see comments for explanation

```js
const formPages = [
  {
    "name": "page1",
    "response": [
      {
        "question": "Question 1",
        "response": "Hello!"
      },
      {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "response": "Hello again!"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "page2",
    "response": [
      {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "response": "Bye!"
      },
      {
        "question": "Question 4",
        "response": "Bye again!"
      }
    ]
  }
]
//refer to the placeholder div:
const placeholderDiv = document.getElementById('table-placeholder');
//loop over all pages:
formPages.forEach(page =>{
  //create an element that contains the page
  let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  h2.innerText = page.name;
  
  //add the element to the div
  placeholderDiv.appendChild(h2); 
  
  //create a table within the foreach loop so you get a seperate table for every page
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  //here the headers are set static, you could chose to also make this dynamic and refer to the object.keys for the response for example
  table.innerHTML ='<thead><tr><th>Question</th><th>Response</th></thead>';
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  
  //append the body to the table
  table.appendChild(tbody)
  
  //loop over the responses
  page.response.forEach(question =>{
    //create a row
    let trow = document.createElement('tr')
    //create a cell within the row
    let questionCell = document.createElement('td')
    
    //set the innerText of the cell with the value from question
    questionCell.innerText = question.question;
    
    //create another cell within the row
    let responseCell = document.createElement('td')
    
    //set the innerText of the cell with the value from the response
    responseCell.innerText = question.response;
    
    //append both cells to the row
    trow.appendChild(questionCell);
    trow.appendChild(responseCell);
    
    //append the row to the table body
    tbody.appendChild(trow)
  
  })
  
  //append the entire table to the div
  placeholderDiv.appendChild(table)


})
```

```html
<div id='table-placeholder'> </div>
```

Comment: Excellent - perfect solution for me. Thanks so much for taking your time to help out!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cars = [
  {
    "name": "page1",
    "response": [
      {
        "question": "Question 1",
        "response": "Hello!"
      },
      {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "response": "Hello again!"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "page2",
    "response": [
      {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "response": "Bye!"
      },
      {
        "question": "Question 4",
        "response": "Bye again!"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    //console.log(cars[i])
    text +="<h3>"+cars[i].name+"</h3>";
    text +="<table border=1>";
    text+="<tr><th>Question</th><th>Response</th></tr>";
    for(let j=0;j<cars[i].response.length;j++ ){
        text +="<tr><td>"+cars[i].response[j].question+"</td>";
        text +="<td>"+cars[i].response[j].response+"</td></tr>";
    }
    text +="</table>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript For Loop</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```